# Can preg_match be used as part of an already set variable?

Tags: php, preg-match

Hopefully I phrased that properly.

If i have some variables called `$foo_bar` `$foo_barbar` `$foo_barbarbar`

Is there anyway of using preg_match like `/[A-Z]|[0-9]/i` to use to replace bar, barbar, barbarbar?

Comment: @JohnConde No because I don't know how to properly write such a thing.

Comment: Are you trying to preg replace the **name of the variable**?

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: the question is not clear, do you want to replace the word bar, barbar ....etc in a text or you want to replace content of variable names who have "bar" with something else ?

Comment: @Shehabix No, not replace. I might want something like this to echo all variables starting with $foo and that end in any variation of letters/numbers after the _

Comment: @MichaelN Are you parsing a file? Or do you need to find variables during the script execution?

Comment: @MathieuImbert The latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so via looping on $GLOBALS

But notice that this is exhaustive

```
foreach($GLOBALS as $name => $val){

if(preg_match('/foo[A-Za-z0-9_]*bar/',$name)){
   if(is_array($val)){
     print_r($val);
   }
   else{
    echo $val;
   }
}

}
```